# 'FirebaseAnalytics/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native

On my project after updating to 0.50.4 and RN 0.55 I can't build iOS.
'FirebaseAnalytics/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h' file not found

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post your Xcode structure files.

Comment: @Bassem Hope you can do upvote as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams that `react-native-firebase` is not yet compatible with newest firebase release.

try out this and let me know in case of any queries.

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '4.2.0'
```

Comment: Down vote doesn't make sense, please provide reason for that